# Different location for the dotenv file that is not in the root folder of a Vue application?

Tags: vue.js, configuration, dotenv

Currently, I'm developing a web application that has the following file structure:

```
/client
    |-- /public
    |-- /src
    config files
/server
    |-- /src
    config files
Root folder config files
```

In the root folder, I have a .env file which the "server" directory can access.
However, Vue expects a .env file in the root of it's file structure. So essentially in the "client" directory. If I add a .env file there, the variables are accessible. But I want Vue to access the .env file from the root folder of the whole project.

How can I achieve this? Thank you!